# Find difference between two lists using Eigen

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I would like to find the difference between two lists. For example:

```
// two lists:
A = [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ];
B = [ 1, 4, 5 ];

// difference between the lists:
C = [ 0, 2, 3, 6 ];
```

I have done this using the STL-library of C++ as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  std::vector<size_t> A = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
  std::vector<size_t> B = {1, 4, 5};
  std::vector<size_t> C;

  std::set_difference(A.begin(),A.end(), B.begin(),B.end(), std::inserter(C,C.begin()));

  return 0;
}
```

However, because my application uses mostly Eigen, I now would like to do also this using Eigen. I couldn't find what I was looking for in the documentation nor online.

Note that I specifically want to avoid writing my own function.

Comment: What makes you think Eigen has anything for this?  What's wrong with using what's already in front of you and working?

Comment: if it can be done with the standard library, then why would Eigen bother to implement its own way? "Note that I specifically want to avoid writing my own function." ... not clear at all what you want to avoid, you already have a solution, no need to write your own

Comment: @JohnZwinck It was more of a hope... I want(ed) this to give the best end-user experience by switching as few times as possible (or even never) between from Eigen-vectors and STL-vectors. Of course there is absolutely noting wrong with the proposed STL-solution! *(I'm not at all pro-Eigen, but I want to make this code accessible for non-specialist and I feel that sticking to one thing may help)*

Comment: @TomdeGeus: STL algorithms can be applied to non-STL data structures, including Eigen.

Comment: algorithms work on iterators not containers, I dont know Eigen too much, but I would be surprised if their containers dont provide iterators

Comment: The term "vector" has probably different meanings in std vs. Eigen. In std, vector is a dynamic array (for "any" element type). Eigen vectors are intended for vectors in a mathematical sense. Eigen vectors may or may not use std::vector for implementation.

Comment: @JohnZwink @tobi303 Agreed on both (I've used this also several times). However I am conceptually a bit lost for this example, `std::inserter` lets `C` grow. How would I accomplish the same with Eigen? Allocate `C` to the maximum length of `A` and `B` and let `std:: set_difference` work its magic? But how would I then know how long `C` is? By initializing it first?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

int main()
{
    using namespace Eigen;

    VectorXd a(3), b(1);
    VectorXd c(a.size());

    a << 1,2,3;
    b << 1;

    auto it = std::set_difference(a.data(), a.data() + a.size(), 
                                  b.data(), b.data() + b.size(), 
                                  c.data());
    c.conservativeResize(std::distance(c.data(), it)); // resize the result
    std::cout << c;
}
```

The key here is to use [`Eigen::VectorXd::data()`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1PlainObjectBase.html#ad12a492bcadea9b65ccd9bc8404c01f1) member function, which returns a pointer to the underlying storage, which is itself an iterator that can be passed around to C++ standard library functions.

Comment: Awesome, this helps a lot! Just for clarification, in the case of `Eigen::MatrixXd` in principle the same trick could be used right? But this might screw up the number of rows and columns, how could I fix that? *(I realize that `set_difference` might not be the most relevant application for matrices)*

Comment: @TomdeGeus `MatrixXd::data()` will return a pointer to the first element. Eigen is using column-major order, so when incrementing the pointer the matrix will be traversed in column-major order, i.e. if `A << 1,2,3,4`, the pointer will point to `1,3,2,4` respectively. And yes, matrix "differences" in set-theoretical terms don't make too much sense.

Comment: Clear. But may I change the number of entries? I guess the answer is yes, based on your answer. However, how do I decide how to change the number of rows and columns (and store this to the matrix variable)?

Comment: @TomdeGeus What do you mean? Are you talking about reshaping the matrix?

Comment: Exactly. Suppose that I would have done the example on matrices, but then to match entire columns. Then `C` would still have an undefined number of rows and columns right? Or should `C` be a `Vector` first, which would than be mapped to a `Matrix` (using [`Map`](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Map.html)).

Comment: @TomdeGeus I'd definitely make the output (i.e. `C`) a vector, after all the result is a set and shouldn't have dimensions. The as you said can map it back to a matrix via `Eigen::Map` if you really want.

Comment: You should probably check the return value of `std::set_difference` and resize `c` afterwards (using `conservativeResize`). Also, `c` should be initialized to the size of `a`, in case there are no common elements.